# Can I use c# on the client side?

Tags: windows

I'm teaching myself, I have learned HTML, CSS, Javascript (still learning) and quite a bit about C#.

My question is can I use the C# that I have learned on the client side? if it's possible, I have made several webpages using ASP.net, I have added a class to a project and I'm stuck.

If it's possible to use C# the way I'm explaining it, how do I link the class page to the project and run it?
.

Comment: What makes you think you can't use C# for things other than ASP.net web programming?  What do you mean by a "Class page"?

Comment: Think about it this way, would you like it if a random website could run an arbitrary program that could do whatever it wanted, like for example install a program that recorded every key you press on your computer? There are ways to do it (See Chris O's answer).

Comment: Short answer is no. No one would trust your code, and would leave your site.

Comment: Thanks Scott. To put it straight forward I taught myself c# and I simply want to use c# and not have to to use the Console.WiteLine.

Comment: @user2731196 - What? That makes no sense... How else would you write to the console? Or, are you trying to write a string in a browser? If so, use `Response.Write();`

Comment: Please don't do such edits, you've completely changed the question. I've reverted it to the previous state. If you have another question, ask it (and do it in the right place, programming questions go to [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/), remember to read Help first).

Answer (score 1):

If you're writing a webpage, then your only option for using C# in the client webbrowser is through an ActiveX control.  So that mean IE-only browsers and a fair pile of security settings to get right, which affects deployment.  If you're doing this only on your machine, then not a problem.  C# code could interact with the DOM from the HTML side of things, otherwise it is just code running in the browser, it has nothing to do with the C# code-behind running by the server.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. To be more specific I am rephrase my question. For weeks I am been studying c# and the "Console.WriteLine". I am now using asp.net and creating a website that is not going to be published. On my webpage I am adding a class by selecting add new item. I write my c# code. How can I see my c# code when I press f5 this is what I don't get. I used to write Console.WriteLine what should I do now? Can I create a button and when I click the button see my c# code? Thank you again.

Comment: @user2731196 See [System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.writeline.aspx). It writes to the Output window within Visual Studio.

Comment: @eiennohito,Thank you this is the qnswer I was looking for.

Comment: Sorry I click enter for a new line and my message got posted.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean by 'client' the programming for the web browser, then there are some translators to JS from C#.
See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7667327/best-c-sharp-to-javascript-translator.

Creating offline applications using WinForms and WPF is your another option.

Comment: Hello, I am using visual studio 2012, what is the code to insert a picture from a an image folder in the solution explorer?

Comment: and I just did it again. The folder's name is "image" the picture name is "pic1" here is what I do: <img src="image/pic1.jpg"> and it wont work. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I downloaded visual studio 2013 and I didn't see open "empty razor page" as an option like there was in the 2012 version. Where is it? I try to look for visual studio 2012 to download but it is no where to be found as all the links lead to visual studio 2013. I starting practicing with Databases with visual studio 2012 and I would like to continue. I like to keep using visual studio and not Web Matrix. Thank in advance.